# Solaris SSH Server Log Destinaton IP Address

Tags: ssh, logging, solaris

To stay compliant, it's required that my Solaris 10 SSH server log the destination IP address in addition to the existing port logging. Is it possible to add the destination IP address in the authlog? For example:

**Original**

```
Dec  8 10:19:00 myhost sshd[11167]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted publickey for me from 192.168.1.45 port 32387 ssh2
```

**Correct**

```
Dec  8 10:19:00 myhost sshd[11167]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted publickey for me from 192.168.1.45 port 32387 to 192.168.1.10 port 22 ssh2
```

Thanks!

Comment: You already have this information, as you know from which host the logs are coming from.

Comment: That's not an accurate statement: servers can have more than one interface.

Comment: Ahh yes, good point.

Comment: You could try raising the log level to VERBOSE instead of INFO. I'm not sure if it will be enough, but if it does work I'll make the comment into an answer.

Comment: Verbose doesn't output the destination, just gives more output for keys.